# How to match a specific word from the beginning of a sentence and get the unmatched part in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python and I do not know regular expressions in Python. Here is the question. I have a sentence like "Total Cost: 37" in stdout, I want to extract the cost info which is 37. When I match the words "Total Cost: " in a specific line how should I get the rest of the line which is the info that I am interested in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `regex`:

`Total Cost:\s?` explanation:

"Total Cost": Match the literal `Total Cost:`

`\s?` : `1 to 0 times Whitespace [\t \r\n\f]`

Capturing group `([-+]?\d+)`:

`[-+]?`: `1 to 0 times matches one of the following chars: -+`

`\d+` :`infinite to 1 times Digit [0-9]`

```
In [121]: strs="some text Total Cost: 37 some more more Total Cost: -100"

In [122]: re.findall(r"Total Cost:\s?([-+]?\d+)",strs)
Out[122]: ['37', '-100']
```

Comment: the OP said they wanted to return the rest of the line

Comment: OP says **"I want to extract the cost info which is 37"**.

Comment: what should I add to handle negative numbers?

Comment: @fatma.ekici I've edited the code, now it handles negative numbers as well.

Comment: I tried it. When I used this regex with re.search() it gave me Total Cost = -1 but your solution is correct when I use re.findall(). What is the difference between them?

Comment: Don't use `re.search()` here, it used to find whether a particular pattern is there in the string or not. while `re.findall()` returns all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string.
read the docs for more detail.http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: (re.search()).group(0) returns the matched string, what is the drawback of finding the matched string in that way?

Comment: @fatma.ekici It'll not work if multiple `Total Cost:` are present in the string.Plz read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Though you said the question was related to "regex," I focus on what you were saying about the output. You have an STDOUT of:

```
Total Cost: 37
```

Assume this output is stored in a string called `output_string`. I use the Python interpreter:

```
In [11]: output_string = "Total Cost: 37"

In [13]: (total_text_string, total_numeric_string) = 
         output_string.split(':')

In [14]: total_text_string
Out[14]: 'Total Cost'

In [15]: total_numeric_string
Out[15]: ' 37'

In [16]: float(total_numeric_string)
Out[16]: 37.0
```

We take the string, use the `split` method, with ":" as a delimiter. We end up with two strings, one for the textual portion, one containing the numerical portion. Since you likely want the cost to contain decimals, you can "cast" it into a floating point via "float". You can then decide what you want to do with these values.